# [C#]Socket programming, Client interface

Tags: c#, sockets, server, client

i have a Client/Server multithreaded programm that is working.
My Question is, how can i select any Client and send him packets from the server?

Comment: If your programs are connected via TCP sockets then you will have one socket stored in the server per client.  Send the message to the relevant socket.

Comment: Yes, i use TCP Sockets. But i create always a new Socket for a new Client. Also i need a "List", but which?

Comment: Yes you create a new socket for each Client, so if you want to send a message to one Client then send it via the socket that you have stored for that client.  If you don't know which socket is for which client, but you need to send it to a particular client, then you'll need to send sufficient information from each client to allow the server to determine which client is which.  But that's completely under your own control.

Comment: Yes i understand, but when i want to send a Packet to a Client, i need an Event by the Clients or not? That the Clients see, when he receive Packets.

Comment: I don't think I understand your problem.  Send data to the socket for the correct client.  In that client read the packet from its socket.  That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do, is to create a `Client` class that contains a `Socket` and when there is a new incoming connection, I create a new Client and gave him the current server instance (`this`) and define the client socket.

Client class:

```
public class Client
{
     public int Id;
     public Socket socket;
     public Server serverInstance;

     public Client(Server server, Socket sock)
     {
         this.Id = GenerateNewUniqueId(); // Generates a unique id (you must implement it :p)
         this.serverInstance = server;
         this.socket = sock;
     }
}
```

Server accept connection:

```
List<Client> clients = new List<Client>();

// incoming connection
void AcceptConnection()
{
    Client newClient = new Client(this, serverSocket.Accept());

    clients.Add(newClient);
}
```

So if you want to send to one or all clients you can do something like this:

```
public void SendPacketToAll()
{
    foreach (Client client in this.clients)
        client.socket.Send(...);
}

public void SendPacketToUserById(int id)
{
    foreach (Client client in this.clients)
        if (client.Id == id)
            client.socket.Send(...);
}
```

Hope it helps, good luck

Comment: Thank u. But when i want to send a Packet to a Client, i need an Event by the Clients or not? That the Clients see, when he receive Packets.

Comment: You have two ways to recieve data with a socket. On client or server side. On the socket documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket(v=vs.110).aspx there is a method called `BeginRevieve` that takes a callback method. This method is for an asynchronous process.
If you want a synchronous process you can do a `while (true)` statement and inside this loop, you can check if there is avaliable data with the `socket.Poll()` method.